# iReport crashes when using certain fonts

Tags: java, jasper-reports, glassfish

I have a problem with Ireport. I've been asked to design a new report for my company, and they gave me an specific font (Kiona). I imported that font in iReport, but when I try to use it, (changing some text to that font), iReport closes right there, so I changed ireport.conf jdk and it worked.

The problem is when I'm implementing this report in java, because when I run my application and click the button that saves a pdf using that report with that font, the server *(glassfish 3.1)* stops right there, and I have to start it again with the command in cmd.

I'm using *iReport 3.7.4* with *jdk1.7.0_80*. When I change to *jdk1.6.0_07* in iReport config, then works. But the real problem resides when glassfish server stops when trying to use that font.

I've looked in a lot of pages, but can't find any info about it.

I'd really apreciate some help to understand why this happen and how to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: If possible, upgrade to the latest version of JasperReports and use JDK 1.8. Otherwise, upgrade to JasperReports 6.5.1, which is the most recent version that is compatible with JDK 1.7.